# How to create a UDF in Spark with a parameter of Timestamp/Date type

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I’m trying to create a UDF in Spark 2.2 using the following code:

```
spark.udf.register(
"DAYOFWEEK",
(timestamp: java.sql.Timestamp) => {
  new Timestamp()
  val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
  cal.setTime(timestamp)
  cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
}
```

Later, when the next SQL query is launched:

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(now())
```

The next exception arises:

```
cannot resolve 'UDF:DAYOFWEEK(current_timestamp())' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires bigint type, however, 'current_timestamp()' is of timestamp type.; line 1 pos 7;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a different UDF which takes bigint as parameter?

Comment: `SELECT DAYOFWEEK(now())` doesn't have a problem. you must be passing something else

Answer (score 1):

@Constantine Thanks for the suggestion. The problem was that there was already a UDF registered with the same name but with a Date as parameter:

```
udf.register(
  "DAYOFWEEK",
  (date: Date) => {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.setTime(date)
    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
  }
)
```

Once that the session has only one *DAYOFWEEK* UDF registered, it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> sqlContext.udf.register(
     | "DAYOFWEEK",
     | (timestamp: java.sql.Timestamp) => {
     |   val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
     |   cal.setTime(timestamp)
     |   cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
     | });
res16: org.apache.spark.sql.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,IntegerType,List(TimestampType))

scala> 

scala> val dd = sqlContext.sql("select DAYOFWEEK(now())")
dd: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: int]


scala> dd.show
+---+
|_c0|
+---+
|  4|
+---+
```